# Rock, Paper, Scissor game - how to end when one wins three times?

Tags: c#

I am writing a Rock(Sten), Paper(Påse), Scissor(Sax) game, that plays against the computer. It works and all but I want to break the game when one off the two wins three times. But it keeps looping...
Im really new to programming so excuse if the code is messy... :(
And im Swedish so the code is in Swedish to... Hope you understand, if not ask me..

This is the Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Game ssp = new Game();

            Interaction.MsgBox("Welcome!");

            string Choice = Interaction.InputBox("Chose Rock, Scissor eller Paper:");
            ssp.Start();
            ssp.Seewicharethevinner(Choice);
         }
```

This is the class with the methods that handels the game:

```
string CompusterChoice;

        //Starts the game
        public void Start()
        {
            //Computers hand
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int x = rnd.Next(0, 3);
            if (x == 0)
            { DatornsVal = "Rock"; }
            else if (x == 1)
            { DatornsVal = "Paper"; }
            else if (x == 2)
            { DatornsVal = "Scissor"; }

        }

        //Look who will win
        public void Seewicharethewinner(string _Choice)
        {
            string PlayerChoice = _Choice;
            string _PlayerChoice = _Choice.ToUpper();
            string _ComputerChoice = ComputerChoice.ToUpper(); 

            if (_PlayerChoice == _ComputerChoice)
            {
                Interaction.MsgBox("Tie!\nYour choice was: " + _Choice + "\n" + "Computer choice was: " + _ComputerChoice);
            string Choice = Interaction.InputBox("Chose Rock, Scissor eller Paper:");
            ssp.Start();
            ssp.Seewicharethevinner(Choice);
            }

            else if (_ComputerChoice == "ROCK" && _PlayerChoice == "SCISSOR" || _ComputerChoice == "SICSSOR" && _PlayerChoice == "PAPER" || _ComputerChoice == "PAPER"
                && _PlayerChoice == "ROCK")

            {
                Interaction.MsgBox("You Lose!\nYour choice was: " + _Choice + "\n" + "Computer choice was: " + _ComputerChoice);

                int player = 0;
                int computer = 1;
                Points(computer, player);

            string Choice = Interaction.InputBox("Chose Rock, Scissor eller Paper:");
            ssp.Start();
            ssp.Seewicharethevinner(Choice);
            }

            else if (_ComputerChoice == "ROCK" && _PlayerChoice == "PAPER" || _ComputerChoice == "SICSSOR" && _PlayerChoice == "ROCK" || _ComputerChoice == "PAPER"
                && _PlayerChoice == "SICSSOR")
            {

                Interaction.MsgBox("You won!\nYour choice was: " + _Choice + "\n" + "Computer choice was: " + _ComputerChoice);
                int player = 1;
                int computer = 0;
                Points(computer, player);

            string Choice = Interaction.InputBox("Chose Rock, Scissor eller Paper:");
            ssp.Start();
            ssp.Seewicharethevinner(Choice);
            }


        }
        public void Points(int _computer, int _player)
        {
            int computerpoints = 0;
            int playerpoints = 0;
            if (_computer > _player)
            {
                computerpoints++;
            }
            else
            {
                playerpoints++;
            }
            if (computerpoints == 3)
            {
              Interaction.MsgBox("Computer won three times!");
            }
            if (playerpoints == 3)
            {
                Interaction.MsgBox("You won three times!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where are you counting te number of wins?

Comment: In the method "Poang"

Comment: change `== 3` with `>=3`. It's the first thing that comes to my mind, I don't understand very well this code, with all those `spelarpoangraknare`

Comment: I'd recommend putting code in english on english sites. It helps us, and in turn, helps you. Or at the least, provide more comments on what does what.

Comment: In tradition, I would simply do `while(winCount < 3) { // run game }`. `winCount` is used to store how many wins have passed. The main game will only run while it's under `3` wins. Otherwise it does something else, like display a `win` message. It's a bit hard to understand the code when it's in another language, literally.

Comment: Now the code is in english... hope it looks ok i wrote in a hurry :)

Comment: I tried the "while(winCount < 3) { // run game }. winCount" but cant get it to work.. :/ well my code are in english now hope you understand it better

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rock, Paper, Scissor game - how to end game when one wins three times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391753/rock-paper-scissor-game-how-to-end-game-when-one-wins-three-times)

Comment: Duplicate! and only asked 11 hours ago... and that was also marked as a Duplicate too! sounds like people are just posting their homework here.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like the problem is that in your Poang method you check to see if someone has won 3 times and if so display a message, but after you check that you don't terminate the program.  It just keeps going on as if nothing happened.  Also, your win count variables are locally scoped, so they lose their value every time the function ends.

There are a lot of things that could be done to make this program better, however I am just going to provide the simplest fix here:

```
    public void UtseVinnare(string _Val)
    {
        string SpelareVal = _Val;
        string _SpelarVal = _Val.ToUpper();
        string _DatornsVal = DatornsVal.ToUpper(); 

        if (_DatornsVal == _SpelarVal)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("Oavgjort!\nDitt val var: " + SpelareVal + "\n" + "Datorns val var: " + DatornsVal);
            string Val = Interaction.InputBox("Välj Sten, Sax eller Påse:");
            Starta();
            UtseVinnare(Val);
        }

        else if (_DatornsVal == "STEN" && _SpelarVal == "SAX" || _DatornsVal == "SAX" && _SpelarVal == "PÅSE" || _DatornsVal == "PÅSE"
            && _SpelarVal == "STEN")

        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("Du förlorade!\nDitt val var: " + SpelareVal + "\n" + "Datorns val var: " + DatornsVal);
            int spelare = 0;
            int dator = 1;
            if (Poang(dator, spelare))
            {
                return;
            }
            string Val = Interaction.InputBox("Välj Sten, Sax eller Påse:");
            Starta();
            UtseVinnare(Val);
        }

        else if (_DatornsVal == "STEN" && _SpelarVal == "PÅSE" || _DatornsVal == "SAX" && _SpelarVal == "STEN" || _DatornsVal == "PÅSE"
            && _SpelarVal == "SAX")
        {

            Interaction.MsgBox("Du vann!\nDitt val var: " + SpelareVal + "\n" + "Datorns val var: " + DatornsVal);
            int spelare = 1;
            int dator = 0;
            if (Poang(dator, spelare))
            {
                return;
            }
            string Val = Interaction.InputBox("Välj Sten, Sax eller Påse:");
            Starta();
            UtseVinnare(Val);
        }


    }

    int datorpoangraknare = 0;
    int spelarpoangraknare = 0;

    public bool Poang(int _dator, int _spelare)
    {
        if (_dator > _spelare)
        {
            datorpoangraknare++;
        }
        else
        {
            spelarpoangraknare++;
        }
        if (datorpoangraknare == 3)
        {
          Interaction.MsgBox("Datorn vann tre gånger!");
          return true;
        }
        if (spelarpoangraknare == 3)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("Du vann tre gåger!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried the "Poang" but i says that "The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item" on "static int datorpoangraknare = 0;
                         static int spelarpoangraknare = 0;"

Comment: @user3356636 OK, I couldn't remember if you could do that in C# or not.  Just make the variables global.  Edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to fix your code with the current methods I would suggest adding the following to make your code easier to follow:

**1: Use enums to give a clear meaning to numbers.**

```
public enum Choice
{
    Rock,
    Paper,
    Scissor
}

public enum WinResult
{
    Won,
    Tie,
    Lost
}
```

**2: Add a method to ask input from user and return the result.**

```
private Choice GiveChoice()
{
    // This is a label where we can jump to if the input was invalid.
    start:

    // Ask the question.
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Choose (0:Rock, 1:Paper, 2:Scissor):");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();
    int result = -1;

    // Validate and re-ask if invalid.
    if (!int.TryParse(answer, out result) || (result < 0 && result > 2))
        goto start;

    return (Choice) result;
}
```

**3: Add a method to compare 2 results from eachother.**

```
// Returns if v1 has won, tied or lost from v2. (Left to right)
private WinResult CompareForWinner(Choice v1, Choice v2)
{
    if (v1 == Choice.Paper)
    {
        if (v2 == Choice.Paper)
            return WinResult.Tie;
        if (v2 == Choice.Rock)
            return WinResult.Lost;

        return WinResult.Won;
    }
    if (v1 == Choice.Rock)
    {
        if (v2 == Choice.Paper)
            return WinResult.Lost;
        if (v2 == Choice.Rock)
            return WinResult.Tie;

        return WinResult.Won;
    }

    // v1 = Scissor.
    if (v2 == Choice.Paper)
        return WinResult.Won;
    if (v2 == Choice.Rock)
        return WinResult.Lost;

    return WinResult.Tie;
}
```

It's not a direct answer to your question. But I think it will help you solve it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the answer to this question should be go and read a book on programming c#?

I noticed that this is marked as a Duplicate above. When you go to that Duplicate that too is marked as a duplicate and only 11 hours ago.

I really don't think people should be just posting up their homework....

Comment: Asking around is the quickest and the most fun way to learn. But, SO's rules are there to be followed ;)